# Virtualbox Host Ubuntu 17.10, guest Windows 7 cannot get access to the sd card

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, sd-card

I have a laptop running Ubuntu 17.10 and it has Virtualbox installed (Version 5.1.20 r114628 (Qt5.7.1)). For my guest system running Windows 7, I want to have access to the Sd-card.

I added the USB device to my virtual machine running Windows, called **Lenovo Integrated SmartCard Reader[100]** (via the menu)

The Lenovo Integrated SmartCard Reader is visible in the Device Manager of Windows and is installed with the proper driver.

However, if I insert a sd-card, my host os (Ubuntu) takes hold of it. I already removed the automount option with the dconf-editor. Tried several times unmount etc but no luck so far.

Any hint how to get the actual memory card visible in my guest os?

Update:

1. Added the same device also to the device filters of Virtualbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stopped trying to get my internal sd card reader to work in my guest OS.

Instead, I found a tip to just buy a cheap external USB sd card reader. This reader was easy to hook up to the guest OS in Virtualbox and could easily read/write and format the sd card.

This was faster than finding out why the internal reader did not work properly. Hope this information can also help other people.

Cheers,
EmbedWise

Embedded Systems Enthusiast - https://www.embedwise.com/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the option vboxmanage --usbcardreader on|off: Enables/disables the USB card reader interface?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15916513)

Comment: Question:Any hint how to get the actual memory card visible in my guest os? Response:
Try the option vboxmanage --usbcardreader on|off

Comment: I tried to vboxmanage --usbcardreader on (as explained here and in Oracle´s documentation): Syntax error: Invalid command '--usbcardreader' - As always when I come in touch with Oracle-Products I can´t find anything in Google or elsewhere if I add the above error as search term in different variations.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was from three years ago, but...

I battled for hours, trying to get the built-in Broadcom smartcard reader in this Dell brick to read from a Windows 10 guest on an Ubuntu 18.04 host, and the device could not be seen.

The missing piece turned out to be

```
sudo adduser $USERNAME vboxusers
```

then restarting the Ubuntu host.